# sending emails using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

am trying to send an email using the following code 
   $this->load->library('email', $config);

```
        $this->email->from('leena.nasir552@gmail.com');
        $this->email->to('leena.nasir@morgan.com');     
        $this->email->subject('my email');     
        $this->email->message($message);

       $result = $this->email->send() ;
       echo($result) ;

        if($this->email->send())

            {

            $params = array (

                'SenderId'=>     $senderId,
                'ReceiverId'=>   $recieverId,
                'Message'=>       $message,
                'Status' =>       'Sent'             // set the statues variable to Sent if it sent successfully

                    );

            $this->UserModel->addMessage($params);

            }  else {
            echo $this->email->print_debugger();

                $params = array (

                    'SenderId' =>     $senderId,
                    'ReceiverId' =>   $recieverId,
                    'Message'=>       $message,
                    'Status' =>       'failed'      // set the status to failed if the message sending failed

                        );

                $this->UserModel->addMessage($params);

                  }
```

the problem that i get this error each time i try to send an email

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: Subject

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 982

can anyone help me solving this error ? giving that this is line 982 from the Email.php libarary

```
$this->_subject = $this->_headers['Subject'];
```

Comment: did you try giving $this->_subject a default value? Does it send if you give it a default value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove these two lines

```
 $result = $this->email->send() ;
 echo($result) ;
```

Because you are trying to send the email twice with another "send" here

```
 if($this->email->send())
```